# AjaxControlToolkit - asp:HtmlEditorExtender problem with Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a problem with Chrome only(with IE and Firefox the page works fine), in aspx page that uses "asp:HtmlEditorExtender" tag and the ajaxcontroltoolkit assembly is included.
The error message on the Chrome console is :
*Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'collapse' on 'Selection': There is no child at offset 3.*

and the line of js code indicated is the following:
sel.collapse(this._editableDiv.firstChild, char);

I follow the workaround suggested in this link:
http://guerriandrea.blogspot.com/2015/01/problem-between-chrome-and.html

but the problem remains when saving the formatted content within the text area; the error remains client.
I tried to update the ajaxcontroltoolkit library and the bug doesn't show up ... the problem is that I would like to avoid updating this library as it is used by almost every page of my application and I would have to test all the functions again.

Thank you very much

Comment: no suggestion?I would like to workaround webresource.axd script error to allow normal page postback and save text in DB. Now with the normal text the saving works well, if the text contained in the HtmlEditorExtender is formatted for example in bold, the script error called runtime from the AjaxControlToolkit library is generated and the page postback is stopped(only with Chrome browser).

Comment: I not seeing this error. I mean, you can download the ajaxtoolkit - it is open sourced. So, if you know the line of code and the bug - then you can modify that code - re-compile the ajaxtoolkit, and your issue should be gone. I use Edge and FireFox, and I use the ajaxtookit editor quite a bit - and I not seen your issue. So, until you post a nice easy to re-produce example here - I really don't' have anything to go do. The idea that someone here is going to take say a whole afternoon to try and build + reproduce or find your error is beyond insane.

Comment: You will need to post the most simple markup - say one textbox, the ajax editor extender, and a minimal re-production of your error. I as noted never seen your issue - but then again, based on what you provided, I have no idea even how to re-produce that error anyway.  So, setup a working re-production on a web page. The markup should be no more then a few line of markup (textbox + extender). And a sub-mit button. Post that super simple example in your question - and we can try it.

Comment: And why would updating the ajaxtoolkit code be a issue for you? If you update that toolkit, then your  whole web site and any thing in that web site that uses the toolkit will of course now be using your updated version. I fail to grasp why if you updated the toolkit, it would not apply to your whole web site?

Comment: updating the ajaxcontroltoolkit library would affect the whole application, for this reason after the update I would have to run a total functionality test. since the bug only appears on this page (only with Chrome), where the "HtmlEditorExtender" object is used, I was wondering if anyone had used a workaround to get around the client script side error (runtime loaded scriptresource.axd) as seen in the forum mentioned.
There are no particular uses of the object, below what is present in the front-end page (aspx):

Comment: `<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server" >  
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
...
<asp:TextBox ID="TBox" runat="server" Text="" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="100" Rows="8"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HtmlEditorExtender EnableSanitization="false" ID="HEditor" runat="server" TargetControlID="TBox" DisplaySourceTab="true" >
            <Toolbar> 
               ...
            </Toolbar>
            </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
`

Comment: the Chrome console error message at scriptresource linked is: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'collapse' on 'Selection': The offset 3 is larger than the node's length (1)."

Comment: for those who need it, I used the workaround of blanks but on the client side; before the calls for the axd (js) controls I inserted a js function (Chrome only) which prepends 3 blank spaces before the message as follows: `msg ="   "+ origMsg;
document.getElementById ("MainContent_HEditor_ExtenderContentEditable"). innerHTML = msg; `

in this way the postback from Chrome is not blocked. Regards